# Touchend fired before blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I'm trying to implement the 'tap' event using 'touchend'. Unfortunately when having focus on input, the 'blur' event of the input is fired after the 'touchend'.

Reproduce: focus input => tap button

```
$(body).append("<div id='abc'>" +
    "<input class='text' type='text'/>" +
    "<button href='#'>save</button>" +
    "</div>");
var $input = $("#abc").children("input");
$input.bind("blur", function () {
    alert("blur");
});
var $button = $("#abc").children("button");
$button.bind("touchend", function (event) {
    alert("touchend");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'touchend' event is no 'click' event. To simulate the 'click' event, setting a focus is needed before doing the click logic.
Below is the code to do the trick. Don't look at the globals, it's just the idea. Also no checks for multi-touch, etc.

```
$(body).append("<div id='abc'>" +
    "<input class='text' type='text'/>" +
    "<button href='#'>save</button>" +
    "</div>");
var $input = $("#abc").children("input");
$input.bind("blur", function () {
    alert("blur");
});
var $button = $("#abc").children("button");
$button.bind("touchend", function (event) {
    if (!swipeDetected) {
        $button.focus();
        //Click logic here
    }
    alert("touchend");
});

var swipeDetected = false,
    startPos = null;
$(document.body).bind("touchstart", function (event) {
    swipeDetected = false;
    var touchEvent = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
    startPos = {
        pageX: touchEvent.pageX,
        pageY: touchEvent.pageY
    };
});
$(document.body).bind("touchmove", function (event) {
    var touchEvent = event.originalEvent.touches[0];
    if (Math.abs(startPos.pageX - touchEvent.pageX) > 10 || Math.abs(startPos.pageY - touchEvent.pageY) > 10) {
        swipeDetected = true;
    }
});
```